# Open/read command in Tcl 8.5 for large files

Tags: tcl

Sorry if the title doesn't match my question well, I'm still unsure as to how I should put it.

Anyway, I've been using Tcl/Tk on Windows (`wish`) for a while now and haven't encountered any problem on the script I wrote until recently. The script is supposed to break down a large txt file into smaller files that can be imported to excel (I'm talking about breaking down a file with maybe 25M lines which comes around 2.55 GB).

My current script is something like that:

```
set data [open "file.txt" r]
set data1 [open "File Part1.txt" w]
set data2 [open "File Part2.txt" w]
set data3 [open "File Part3.txt" w]
set data4 [open "File Part4.txt" w]
set data5 [open "File Part5.txt" w]


set count 0
while {[gets $data line] != -1} {
    if {$count > 4000000} {
        puts $data5 $line
    } elseif {$count > 3000000} {
        puts $data4 $line
    } elseif {$count > 2000000} {
        puts $data3 $line
    } elseif {$count > 1000000} {
        puts $data2 $line
    } else {
        puts $data1 $line
    }
    incr count
}

close $data
close $data1
close $data2
close $data3
close $data4
close $data5
```

And I alter the numbers within the `if` to get the desired number of lines per file, or add/remove any `elseif` where required.

The problem is, with the latest file I got, I end up with only about half the data (1.22 GB instead of 2.55 GB) and I was wondering if there was a line which told Tcl to ignore the limit that it can read. I tried to look for it, but I didn't find anything (or anything that I could understand well; I'm still quite the amateur at Tcl ^^;). Can anyone help me?

**EDIT (update):**
I found a program to open large text files and managed to get a preview of the contents of the file directly. There are actually 16,756,263 lines. I changed the script to:

```
set data [open "file.txt" r]
set data1 [open "File Part1.txt" w]

set count 0
while {[gets $data line] != -1} {
    incr count
}
puts $data1 $count
close $data
close $data1
```

to get where the script is blocking and it stopped here:
[image]

There's a character that the text editor is not recognising in the middle line showing as a little square. I tried to use `fconfigure` like evil otto suggested but I'm afraid I don't quite understand how the `channelID`, `name` or `value` work exactly to escape that character. Um... help?

**reEDIT** : I managed to find out how `fconfigure` worked! Thanks evil otto! Um, I'm not sure how I can 'choose' your answer since it's a comment instead of a proper answer...

Comment: Is 1.22 a combined size of resulting files? Is input file text or binary?

Comment: That should work; large-file support was added in 8.4 and you're not trying to read all the data in at once…

Comment: Is it possible there is any binary data in "file.txt"?  Under windows, tcl will flag eof if it reads a `^Z` (the default `eofchar`) in a file.  You can turn this off with `fconfigure` - see the docs for details.

Comment: @pn8830: 1.22 GB is a combined size (size of the smaller files together), but also individual files. Say I change it so that it copies every line into a single new file, that file will be 1.22 GB. It is a text file.

Comment: @Donal: Okay, so you are saying that the script actually reads the file line by line and there shouldn't be any limit? That's what I believed initially, but with that file, I started having doubts. Maybe there's a character somewhere in the file that causes it?

Comment: @evil otto: Maybe there's one, I didn't know that special character. I'll look into it, thanks! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible there is any binary data in "file.txt"? Under windows, tcl will flag eof if it reads a `^Z` (the default `eofchar`) in a file. You can turn this off with `fconfigure`:

```
fconfigure $data -eofchar {}
```

See the docs for full details.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your script on a Mac, which is Unix-based, and noticed the following:

1. The `incr count` should be at the beginning of the loop--a minor point.
2. More importantly, *File.txt* contains 25M lines, yet you divided unevenly: the first four each contains 1M, and the rest goes into *File5.txt*. If you want to evenly divide the files, then the break points should be 20M, 15M, 10M and 5M.
3. Other than that, I did not notice any data loss. I don't have a Windows machine to try it out.

Comment: Um, yes, I adjust the script accordingly so I get no data loss. The above was just a sample of the script which is similar to what I used.